# How to choose an operator just one time, instead of repeating the test inside a loop?

Tags: ruby

Here's what I'm trying to refactor:

```ruby
items.each_with_index do |item, ndx|
  if side == :left
    condition = ndx < max
  else
    condition = ndx >= max
  end

  result_items << item if condition
end
```

I'd like to be able to move that if/else/end outside the block, since the value of `side` never changes inside the block.  Since the only thing changing based on the value of `side` is the operator, I'd like to be able to do something like:

```ruby
if side == :left
  oper = <
else
  oper = >=
end

items.each_with_index do |item, ndx|
  result_items << item if ndx oper max
end
```

But of course, that won't work because of the syntax.

Is there anyway to store an operator, or a better way to accomplish what I'm after here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Operators are just methods:

```
ndx.public_send(:<=, max)
```

Is the same as

```
ndx <= max
```

So outside the loop set `oper` to the symbol for the desired operator and inside

```
result_items << item if ndx.public_send(oper, max)
```

( you'll have to use `send` rather than `public_send` if you're still stuck on 1.8)

Comment: Best direct answer to the question

Comment: On Ruby 1.9 or later, you should really get into the habit of using `public_send` instead of `send` to match the behavior of a normal method call (i.e. not circumventing `private`). Otherwise, your refactored loop will have different behavior than the original one in the presence of `private` methods.

Answer (score 2):

Check out "proc" and "lambda". They enable you to hold a reference to, letssay, a anonymous function:

```
[4] pry(main)> func = proc {|left, right| left < right}
=> #<Proc:0x34c83c0@(pry):4>

[5] pry(main)> func.call(4,5)
=> true

[6] pry(main)> func.call(5,2)
=> false
```

Note that the 'proc' expects a "block" to be passed, and that block will be later "call"ed with given params. This is the same syntax as if you'd use a `map` or `each` - that's all blocks there. `proc` just returns you that block instead of invoking it.

So, your code can look similar to:

```
if side == :left
  oper = proc{|a,b| a<b}
else
  oper = proc{|a,b| a>=b}
end

items.each_with_index do |item, ndx|
  result_items << item if oper.call(ndx, max)
end
```

I've not checked that code, can have some typos.

Answer (score 2):

If I’ve understood your intentions here, another way could be to use `take` and `drop`:

```
result_items = if side == :left
    items.take max
else
    items.drop max
end
```

Comment: Best refactoring.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If it is okay for you to tweak this logic a bit, you may also achieve the same like:

```
items.each_with_index do |item, ndx|
  # assuming it to be Fixnum since you are using index value
  result_items << item if (max - ndx).abs >= 0
end
```